# Plotting lda-object in R

Tags: r, plot, lda

I am trying to plot a lda-object created with the `lda`-function of the `MASS` package.

The data I am using is here:
https://pastebin.com/yjfmsE3F

My current code is:

```
types <- c('GO', 'GO', 'GO', 'GO', 'GO', 'OO', 'OR', 'OO', 'OO', 'GO', 'GR', 'OO', 'OO', 'GO')
bacDummy <- t(bacCountData)
bacDummy2 <- decostand(bacDummy, "freq")
bacDummy3 <- cbind(types, bacDummy2)
colnames(bacDummy3)[1] <- "Site"
bacDummy4 <- as.data.frame(bacDummy3)
```

with `decostand` being form the `vegan` package.

I then went ahead and tried to use the `lda`-function:

```
bac.lda <- lda(bacDummy4[,2:170], grouping=types)
```

which gives me the following error:

```
Error in lda.default(x, grouping, ...) : 
  variables   4  53 114 138 appear to be constant within groups
```

I then deleted the troubling columns (even though I know it the dirty work around):

```
bacDummy4 <- bacDummy4[,-139]
bacDummy4 <- bacDummy4[,-115]
bacDummy4 <- bacDummy4[,-54]
bacDummy4 <- bacDummy4[,-5]
```

This let me do the LDA, however with the warning: `In lda.default(x, grouping, ...) : variables are collinear`

When I try to plot the groups in a scatter plot I get the following error:

```
plot(bac.lda)
Error in FUN(x, aperm(array(STATS, dims[perm]), order(perm)), ...) : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

What am I doing wrong? If I do `str(bac.lda)` I get this output:

```
List of 8
 $ prior  : Named num [1:4] 0.5 0.0714 0.3571 0.0714
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "GO" "GR" "OO" "OR"
 $ counts : Named int [1:4] 7 1 5 1
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "GO" "GR" "OO" "OR"
 $ means  : num [1:4, 1:165] 6.14 1 2.2 5 2.14 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:4] "GO" "GR" "OO" "OR"
  .. ..$ : chr [1:165] "ReferenceOTU1484" "ReferenceOTU893" "ReferenceOTU1445" "ReferenceOTU623" ...
 $ scaling: num [1:165, 1:3] -0.01649 -0.03767 -0.00607 0.04141 -0.03966 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:165] "ReferenceOTU1484" "ReferenceOTU893" "ReferenceOTU1445" "ReferenceOTU623" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "LD1" "LD2" "LD3"
 $ lev    : chr [1:4] "GO" "GR" "OO" "OR"
 $ svd    : num [1:3] 4.54 3.06 2.03
 $ N      : int 14
 $ call   : language lda(x = bacDummy4[, -1], grouping = bacDummy4$Site)
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "lda"
```

All help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take care to carefully track the datatypes of your variables during each transformation. I ran into a few problems with the code you provided. This seems to work

```
bacCountData <- read.csv("https://pastebin.com/raw/yjfmsE3F", header=T, row.names=1)
types <- c('GO', 'GO', 'GO', 'GO', 'GO', 'OO', 
    'OR', 'OO', 'OO', 'GO', 'GR', 'OO', 'OO', 'GO')

bacDummy <- t(bacCountData)
bacDummy2 <- vegan::decostand(bacDummy, "freq")
bacDummy3 <- data.frame(types=types, bacDummy2)
colnames(bacDummy3)[1] <- "Site"

bac.lda <- MASS::lda(bacDummy3[,-c(1, 5, 54, 115, 139)], grouping=types)
plot(bac.lda)
```

And produces the following plot

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Have you any idea where exactly my error was?

Comment: I'm guessing the `cbind`. You should never mix data.types with `cbind` because by default it works on matrixes which can only hold a single atomic data type unlike data.frames which can hold values of different types.